# Wordpress entry-content empty, php code in div returns nothing

Tags: php, wordpress

A site I made required the display of WordPress post information (title, tags, thumbnails). The PHP code which gets this information from published posts works on my localhost and the post data displays properly.

I just uploaded the site onto my host's server, configured the WP settings to be identical to my localhost WP install, and while 99% of the site works as expected, the information for posts does not display.

There are 3 test posts on the live site currently. I can see 3 article tags through the DOM inspector, so the WP loop to retrieve posts works fine. However, within each article tag, the entry-content tag, which should contain the data, is empty.

All other php code is executing but this little block. Anyone have some advice on resolving the issue?

Here are images (yellow highlight showing the article tags):

First one of the live server, the empty div:

http://imgur.com/rF229Wk

Second on of the localhost, data displaying fine:

http://imgur.com/tMCOg0S

Here is the relevant code:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

   <div class="entry-content">

     <?php

        $images = get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'numberposts' => 999 ) );
        if ( $images ) :
        $total_images = count( $images );
        $image = array_shift( $images );
        $image_img_tag = wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, 'thumbnail' );
     ?>
```

and just below that code is the PHP that displays the thumbnail...(the PHP display code for the other post data like title is omitted). None of the data displays on the site:

```
<figure class="gallery-thumb">

                <span class="image-wrapper">

<?php echo $image_img_tag; ?>
```

All these divs and the figure tags are closed properly further below the page.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is it possible that the post has no attached images? Did you create that post and attach the image(s) online or did you export it from your localhost install?

Comment: @Dehalion Thanks for replying. The images are attached as "featured images", an option that appears on posts. I created it on the live site, no import. Commenting out the echo $image_img_tag block will still display all the other post info (title, tag). Here is the code with echo commented out from my localhost: http://imgur.com/kTI50GW

The article tag is open showing the entry-content tag which contains the appropriate divs...img tag is commented out.

Comment: This is from another page from this site. Excuse the URL. The thumbnails are called and they display properly at the bottom of the white box: http://69.195.124.73/~orgnlca/2013/06/24/this-is-another-test-post/

Comment: and you are sure `$images` doesn't evaluate to `false` or an empty array and your `if` ends before figure?

Comment: @Dehalion Thanks. Definitely on the right path with what you just said. My if statement ended at the bottom of the page. I added endif before figure. The entry-content tag is filled with relevant post data now. The thumbnail is not there yet though. Any other advice? I'm going to test a few things with the images variable.

Comment: So your `$images` is empty. Maybe you didn't upload your image to the post in question but to some other post or directly in the media center and just set it as "featured image". This is not the same as attaching it to the post by uploading it. You should try to get the images by meta name instead (e.g. `get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'featured_image' )` or something like that).

Comment: I'll look into that. Makes sense! Thank you very much for your help. I would certainly be lost without it. Is there anyway I can mark you as correct or upvote you? First time actually posting on stackoverflow.

Comment: I can put it into a proper answer so you can upvote :D Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `$images` variable is empty (or false) and your `if` statement doesn't end before `<figure>`.

Images are attached to a post on upload only. If you use an image from the media center for featured image it won't be attached to the post. You can retrieve this image by getting the meta field using `get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'featured_image' )` or if you are using the featured image you can also use `get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )`.